# Getting same Video Thumbnail Image every time from the Url in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, avasset, video-thumbnails

I am developing a video based Application in Swift3. Where I have one video url and a Range Slider according to the video duration and user can select any minimum and maximum value from slider. If suppose user has selected min value 3 Sec and Max Value 7 Sec, So for this duration I need to generate a Video Thumbnail Image. For this I am using `AVAssetImageGenerator` to generate this, I tried below both code to achieve this :

```
func createThumbnailOfVideoFromFileURL(_ strVideoURL: URL) -> UIImage?{

        let asset = AVAsset(url: strVideoURL)
        let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let time = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
        let img = try? assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)

        guard let cgImage = img else { return nil }

        let frameImg    = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return frameImg
    }
```

---

```
func generateThumbnailForUrl(vidUrl:URL) -> UIImage {

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: vidUrl, options: nil)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        var thmbnlImg = UIImage()
        do{
            let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
            thmbnlImg = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            thmbnlImg = thmbnlImg.imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: 90.0, flip: false)
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
        // !! check the error before proceeding
        return thmbnlImg
    }
```

But the problem is I am getting same thumbnail image using both above methods, bcos I am not setting duration here in both methods. How can I add minimum and maximum duration to generate different thumbnail image for each different duration. Please help me resolve my problem. Thank you!

Edit: I tried to set duration like :

`let time: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(rangeSlider!.lowerValue, 1)`

Then I am getting different thumbnail image but for some slider ranges I am getting nil thumbnail image also. Can anyone have some idea how to set preferredTimeScale value in `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
static func generateThumbnail(videoUrl: String) -> UIImage? {

    do {
        let url                                         = URL(string: videoUrl)
        let asset                                       = AVURLAsset(url: url!)
        let imageGenerator                              = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform   = true
        let cgImage                                     = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTime(seconds: 2.0, preferredTimescale: 60),
                                                                                         actualTime: nil)

        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

    } catch {

        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assume, your trimmed video URL is `videoURL`. After successfully trimming a video, add this code snippet. Actually this code snippet will help you to extract images from trimmed video at each second (meaning, if the duration of your trimmed video is 10 second, this code will extract 10 images at each second and all of these images are saved in an array, named `videoFrames`). Lastly, you can do whatever you want with these images. You can also add an activity indicator while this process is going on. Hope this helps.

```
var videoFrames = [UIImage]()
let asset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoURL as URL)
let videoDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)
let integerValueOFVideoDuration = Int(videoDuration)

//start activity indicator here

for index in 0..<integerValueOFVideoDuration + 1 {
   self.generateFrames(url: videoURL, fromTime: Float64(index))
}

func generateFrames(url: NSURL, fromTime: Float64) {
        if videoFrames.count == integerValueOFVideoDuration {
            //end activity indicator here
            return
        }
        let asset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: url as URL)
        let assetImgGenerate: AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetImgGenerate.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let time: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(fromTime, 600)
        var img: CGImage?
        do {
            img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        } catch {
        }
        if img != nil {
            let frameImg: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: img!)
            videoFrames.append(frameImg)
        } else {
            //return nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, here I don't have trim video Url.. I have only single main video url and a range slider, where user will select min & max value from slider. Using that range values I need to generate a Thumbnail image. Any suggestions...U understand?

Comment: ok...you need to convert your min & max value from slider to CMTimeMakeWithSeconds and pass these value to the above function. fromTime: Float64 is the parameter here.

Comment: Can you show me in code, I changed CMTimeMake values but everytime same thumbnail.

Comment: let lowerVal = Float64(rangeSlider.lowerValue)  & pass this value to the above function. You will get the thumbnail image of lower value. Same way will work for rangeSlider.upperValue. I guess you are using a custom slider here so, it is tough to answer your question here without seeing your full custom slider property.

Comment: I have rangeSlider.lowerValue and rangeSlider.upperValue, How can I add these two values in CMTimeMakeWithSeconds? I don't have any idea about this.

Comment: try this,  
let lowerVal = Float64(rangeSlider.lowerValue) &  let upperVal = Float64(rangeSlider.upperValue) & pass these value to the above function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160377/discussion-between-pigeon-39-and-anand-gautam).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160415/discussion-between-pigeon-39-and-anand-gautam).